# python ttk Button sub components

Tags: python, user-interface, ttk

How can I access the python ttk Button subcomponents?

For a `LabelFrame`, you apply

```
frameStyle = Style()
frameStyle.configure('BW.TLabelframe', background="#272626", foreground="#272626", font=('Arial', 9), relief='flat', bd=1, bg="#272626")

labelStyle = Style()
labelStyle.configure('BW.TLabelframe.Label', background="#272626", foreground="#fff", font=('Arial', 9))
```

Why don't they work on a button? I have tried the following:

```
btnStyle = Style()
btnStyle.configure('BW.TButton.border', background="#fff", foreground="#fff", font=('Arial', 9), relief='flat', bd=1, bg="#272626")
```

also `'BW.TButton.border'`, `'BW.TButton.focus'` and `'BW.TButton.spacing'` don't work, however the [docs](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html) say it should.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following to give the `Button` a border. I had to change it to tkinter, or it wouldn't work

```
self.btnFrame = Frame(self.lblfAudio, bd=1)
self.btnRefresh = Button(self.btnFrame, text="refresh")
self.btnRefresh.configure(bg="#272626", fg="#fff", font=("Arial", 9), bd=0, relief="flat", highlightcolor="#272626", highlightthickness=2)
self.btnRefresh.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=0, padx=0, sticky=N+W)
self.btnRefresh.configure(width=16)
self.btnFrame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N, pady=(5, 10), padx=(0, 10))
```